# How to perform boolean comparison each time a variable is referenced

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean

The purpose of this code is to perform one validation on document ready and a subsequent validation every time the input is changed. The 'do something' lines will be used to update styles on a page based on the state of flag.

In the code below, the flag variable is set twice, once to check immediately if an input value equals 'dog', and again to perform the same comparison after input has changed. How would I rewrite this so that '$firstInput.val() == "dog"' is only written once?

```
var flag = $firstInput.val() == "dog";

//do something with flag var here

$firstInput.on('input', function () {
    flag = $firstInput.val() == "dog";
    //do something with flag var here
})
```

Comment: More details needed to understand the problem. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the first condition at all unless the value of the input is being assigned before the `.on('input')` function is called.

Comment: In other words, just replace `var flag =` conditional assignment with your `.on()` conditional assignment

Comment: can you explain your question more?

Comment: create a function.

Comment: you can create a function and call it twice instead of using that statement, for e.g `function isDog(){ return ($firstInput.val()=='dog'); }` and call it where you want `var flag = isDog();`

Comment: I have failed to understand what is your question or what is the purpose of the above code, can you please provide some additional details like a scenario or use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var flag = null;

function updateFlag(){
   flag = $firstInput.val() == "dog";
}

updateFlag();


//do something with flag var here

$firstInput.on('input', function () {
   updateFlag();
   //do something with flag var here
})
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

**So here's what I took from you:**

a. You have to check the value initially
b. You have to add an input event listener for future checks.
--> basically you *HAVE* to write it twice is what you've stated, correct?

**Sol'n:**

Refactor `$firstInput.val() == "dog";` into a function (because DRY):
`function isDog() { return $firstInput.val() == "dog"; }` like so:

.

```
function isDog() { return $firstInput.val() == "dog"; }
var flag = isDog();

//do something with flag var here

$firstInput.on('input', function () {
    flag = isDog();
    //do something with flag var here
})
```

**Now...ALSO**, *assuming* that`//do something with flag var here` is the *SAME* chunk of code, you could even *further* simplify it all:

```
var flag = false;
function checkIsDog() { flag = $firstInput.val() == "dog"; }

checkIsDog();
$firstInput.on('input', checkIsDog);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In terms of DRY and making use of jQuery which you already use - you could create two mini-plugins for jQuery so that you can re-use that logic wherever you want.
One plugin accepts an `expectation` method where you define what you expect to happen - you can apply this in the usual jQuery manner on multiple elements with chaining - and the other evaluates the expectation. You could also re-use the `expectation` outside these plugins by accessing `$(this).data('expectation')`

```js
$.fn.expect = function(expectation) {
  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).data('expectation', expectation);
  });
}
$.fn.isExpected = function() {
  return $(this).data('expectation').call(this);
}

// Thanks to chaining, .expect() will return the same element(s) again as matched
// previously with $(selector) - only that it adds an expectation to it/them
var $firstInput = $('#inp').expect(function() {
  return $(this).val() == 'dog';
});

console.log($firstInput.isExpected());

$firstInput.on('input', function () {
    console.log($firstInput.isExpected());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="cat" id="inp">
```

**EDIT: Taking it further**

If we would write this in ES6, we could add 2 new properties to the `HTMLInputElement` - where `.expect` can take a function assignment and `.isExpected` acts as a property (no parantheses for a function call, since it has a getter):

```js
Object.defineProperty(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'expect', {
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  writable: true,
  value: function() {
    throw("This input element has no expectation");
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'isExpected', {
  configurable: false,
  enumerable: false,
  get: function() {
    return this.expect.call(this);
  }
});

let inp = document.querySelector('#inp');

// No expectation assigned yet
try { inp.isExpected } catch(e) { console.error(e) }

inp.expect = function() {
  return this.value === 'dog';
}

// Expectation assigned
console.log(inp.isExpected);

inp.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  console.log(this.isExpected);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="cat" id="inp">
```